# How to best create a Timer Function in R

Tags: algorithm, r, timer, tcl

I'm trying to create a function in R that returns for the first x seconds after the function call 1, the next x seconds 0, the next x seconds 1 again,...the whole procedure should stop after another time interval or after n iterations. I want to do this with one function call.

I read about the package tcltk which apparently entails some possibilities to create such "timer" functions, however I did not find enough explanations to sort out my issue.

Could you advise me where to find a good manual that explains tcl in context with R? Do you have other ideas how to create such a function in an efficient way?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to create a function that will return 1 whenever it is called in the first x secs, then return 0 whenever it's called in the next x secs, then return 1 over the next x secs, etc. And after a certain `total` time, it should be "done", maybe return -1?

You could do this using the following function that will "create" a function with any desired interval:

```
flipper <- function(interval=10, total = 60) {
  t0 <- Sys.time()
  function() {
    seconds <- round(as.double( difftime(Sys.time(), t0, u = 'secs')))
    if(seconds > total)
      return(-1) else
    return(trunc( 1 + (seconds / interval ) ) %% 2)
  }
}
```

You can use this to create a function that alternates between 0 and 1 every 10 secs during the first 60 seconds, and returns -1 after 60 seconds:

```
> flp <- flipper(10,60)
```

Now calling `flp()` will have the behavior you are looking for, i.e. when you call `flp()` during the next 60 secs, it will alternate between 1 and 0 every 10 secs, then after 60 secs it will just return -1.

Comment: You want `t0 <- Sys.time`, otherwise you'll modify a `t0` in global scope (if it already exists)

Answer (score 7):

`Sys.sleep` from base could not be a solution?

E.g.: stop every 10th iteration in a loop for 10 seconds:

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    # do something
    if ((i %% 10) == 0) {
        Sys.sleep(10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

May I also suggest:

Timer 1

```
library(data.table)

begin.time <- proc.time()
timetaken(begin.time)
```

Timer 2

```
library(matlab)

tic(gcFirst=FALSE)
toc(echo=TRUE)
```

Both are excellent choices for timers

Answer (score 1):

The tcltk command after will call a function after a time delay. Getting it to repeatedly call can be done along the following lines (made more complicated by this desire to have different intervals between events).

```
afterID <- ""
someFlag <- TRUE
MS <- 5000                              # milliseconds
repeatCall <- function(ms=MS, f) {
  afterID <<- tcl("after", ms, function() {
    if(someFlag) {                      
      f()
      afterID <<- repeatCall(MS - ms, f)
    }  else {
      tcl("after", "cancel", afterID)
    }
  })
}
repeatCall(MS, function() {
  print("Running. Set someFlag <- FALSE to stop.")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timefun <- function(interval = 10, output = c(0, 1)) {

  start <- Sys.time()

  # do some stuff
  for (i in 1:99999) paste(i, i^2)

  # how many intervals did it take
  elapsed <- as.numeric(round(Sys.time() - start)) / interval

  output[elapsed %% length(output) + 1]
}
```

I'm not clear on "the whole procedure should stop after another time interval or after n iterations", do you want to check elapsed time periodically during the function execution and `stop()` if it's above a certain value?